# Convert factor into time in R

Tags: r, time, dataframe

I have a data frame df like:

```
ID  time 
a    121:24:30
b    130:30:00
```

The time column is of factor after importing data.
I want convert the values of time column into minutes. At first, I have tried:

```
df$time <- times(df$time)
```

But I got warning message:

> "out of day time entry"

I notice the value in the hour position is more than 24 in my dataset.

So how am I supposed to do now?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What time shoulf `121:24:30` be interpreted as? So what should be the ourcome?

Comment: Using minutes to represent the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is saved as **dat** use the following

```
#convert to character
dat$time <- as.character(dat$time)
#split by ":"
times <- strsplit(dat$time, ":")
# get minutes
dat$time <- sapply(times, function(x){
  x = as.numeric(x)
  x[1]*60+x[2]+x[3]/60
})
```

Comment: So that means my time is illegal at some point, right? I should use string command extract the number and calculate.

Comment: Yes: Times in the format "%H:%m:%d" with %H not in the range of 0-23 is not implemented in base R. See `? strptime `. This is why i parse the string manually. You could use additional packages and classes like Richard Scriven suggests.

Comment: alright, thanks both of you. I wanna make sure this.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the *lubridate* package for this.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- hms(df$time)
(hour(x) * 60) + minute(x) + (second(x) / 60)
# [1] 7284.5 7830.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I choose floo0's answer. Since I'm new to  R, wanna play more base function. Thanks for introducing the package.

Comment: @Floo0 - Thanks but I don't think White.Big has enough rep to vote yet.  But I did it for him ;)

Comment: Thanks guys! you are all so nice!

Answer (score 2):

Another option (just for fun) is to play around with the `gsubfn` package

```
s <- factor(c("121:24:30", "130:30:00"))
library(gsubfn)
as.numeric(gsubfn("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", 
                  ~ as.numeric(x)*60 + as.numeric(y) + as.numeric(z)/60, 
                  as.character(s)))
## [1] 7284.5 7830.0
```

Comment: Thanks David, appreciate it ~